# Run next job using GNU Parallel only if user defined condition is true

Tags: linux, gnu-parallel

I am running several instances of a program using GNU Parallel and each one requires some space in secondary memory. It happens that, later on in my current setup, all instances exit with error because there is no space left on device.

How can I set GNU Parallel to run next job only when device usage is below 90%? I can get the device usage by using the `df` command: `df --output=pcent "$PWD" | sed '1d;s/[^0-9]//g'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# define a function which "parallel" will call
doit() {
   # wait forever for sufficient resources
   while :; do
      pcnt=$(df --output ...)
      [ $pcnt -lt 90 ] && break
      sleep 5
   done
   # do job now as resources are available

}

# export function to subshells started by "parallel"
export -f doit

# start "parallel" - probably one of 3 methods:
#   parallel -a jobs.txt doit
#   parallel doit ::: jobs
#   generate_jobs | parallel doit
```