# Parallel and bbcp

Tags: linux, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to use parallels with the file transfer program bbcp but there seems to be some parsing issue that I'm unable to figure out. I run the following command and get the following output -

Command -

```
cat testfiles.log | parallel --will-cite -j 5 bbcp -4 c -r -z -Vv -P 2 -S "ssh -x -a -oFallBackToRsh=no %I -l %U %H module load bbcp; bbcp" {} ./testing_parallel/
```

Output -

```
bbcp: /source/path is a directory.  
bbcp: Network is unreachable unable to connect to port [::ffff:IP]:PortNumber  
bbcp: Unable to allocate more than 0 of 4 data streams.  
bbcp: Accept timed out on port PortNumber  
bbcp: Unable to allocate more than 0 of 4 data streams.  
Usage:   bbcp [Options] [Inspec] Outspec  

Options: [-a [dir]] [-A] [-b [+]bf] [-B bsz] [-c [lvl]] [-C cfn] [-D] [-d path]  
         [-e] [-E csa] [-f] [-F] [-g] [-h] [-i idfn] [-I slfn] [-k] [-K]  
         [-L opts[@logurl]] [-l logf] [-m mode] [-n] [-N nio] [-o] [-O] [-p]  
         [-P sec] [-r] [-R [args]] [-q qos] [-s snum] [-S srcxeq] [-T trgxeq]  
         [-t sec] [-v] [-V] [-u loc] [-U wsz] [-w [=]wsz] [-x rate] [-y] [-z]  
         [-Z pnf[:pnl]] [-4 [loc]] [-~] [-@ {copy|follow|ignore}] [-$] [-#] [--]  

I/Ospec: [user@][host:]file  
**bbcp: Value not specified for '-x'.**
```

If I use the command on its own without parallel, it does work and doesnt give the 'value not specified' error. Any idea how to get past this?

Edit 1 - anyone??

Comment: When you have a command of that complexity, it is often simpler to define a function like I did here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/45477339/2836621

Comment: A bit too complex given I have a large amount of parent folders to go through. Running this command would be much more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try changing the order of the commands.
Instead of:

```
"ssh -x -a -oFallBackToRsh=no %I -l %U %H module load bbcp; bbcp"
```

try:

```
"module load bbcp; ssh -x -a -oFallBackToRsh=no %I -l %U %H bbcp"
```

- Some versions of the bbcp are a bit buggy, and difficult to work with. Also I'm not sure if you can run more than one instances of bbcp in parallel (multiple instances of it would try to connect on the same ports; so you may need to specify port range for each instance)
- In your case, I would suggest using an alternative like lftp, without the parallel command, but with the lftp's built-in `--parallel[=N]` option, which achieves the same thing that you are trying to get with GNU parallel.

Comment: You cannot answer a question with another question.  Answers should be definitive and unambiguous.

Comment: @Bill: The last line is a clarifying question that should be a comment; it doesn't make sense as a new question, as the author is not trying to get help on a problem they're having.

Comment: ok removed the question, but can't move it to comments (don't have enough reputation).

Comment: ok removed the comment on the question